# Is a closure that is passed in as a parameter assigned to the parameter name in swift?

Tags: swift, closures

This code is from [this](https://philandrews.io/post/swift-completion-handlers) blog.

Is the reason we can call `completion()` because the closure that's passed in `() -> ()` is essentially assigned to the parameter completion and so calling completion executes the closure?

```
func thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep(completion: () -> ()) {
    print("The quick brown fox")
    completion()
}

func thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond() {
   print("jumped over the lazy dog")
}
```

If that's the case re: calling the function below I don't quite get how the code below translates into the first function being called and completed before the `thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond()` is? What I mean by that is how is the `()->()` in resulting in the `completion()` executing before `thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond()` is called - it's hard explaining this in writing.

```
thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep { () -> () in
    thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond()
}
```

Comment: Unable to understand your question, so re-structure your question so that you got more accurate answer

Comment: @dahiya_boy what does the completion() do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a function with a closure as one of its input parameters, the closure is executed as soon as you call it by `inputParameterName()`. The parentheses after the name of the input parameter mark the function call with no input parameters to the closure, since its type in your case is `Void->Void`.

In your second example,

```
thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep { () -> () in
    thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond()
}
```

you see a trailing closure. If the last input parameter of a function is a closure, the function call can be converted to the trailing closure syntax, where you can omit the name of the closure (completion in your case) and the code between the `{}` will be executed once the closure is called.

So the above code is equivalent to

```
thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep(completion: { () -> () in
    thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond()
})
```

Comment: Thanks! While i understand that this line: thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep(completion: { () -> () in .... will mean that the first function executes before the second function i don't really get why that is the case - why is completion: { () -> () in  happening before thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond()?

Comment: The whole point of closures is that they are only executed when you actually call them. Everything that goes into the completion handler, between `{...}` will only be executed when the closure itself is called, which happens at the end of the `thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep` function. This means that the order of execution will be: everything before the closure in `thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep` runs, then the closure itself is called, then the code inside the completion handler will be called, which in your case is `thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond`.

Comment: Thanks @David. That's brilliant. One last question - when actually calling the function thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep is this the actual closure  { () -> () in thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond() })  and it's only executing because in the function definition at the end of thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep we call completion()?